# Why closed cooling systems require power to run pump?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

For example car's cooling system - it circulates water in same loop. So if water is being pumped upwards, it goes down back again - thus it should result 0 J work. But coolant pumps still require quite a lot of power (~10A) - where does it all go? Is it friction in tubes?

Comment: The pump does't just elevate the water for it to drop. It circulates it.

Comment: Yes, it is viscous friction.

Answer (score 0):

> So if water is being pumped upwards, it goes down back again - thus it
> should result 0 J work.

The pump does't just elevate the water for it to drop. It circulates it.

> But coolant pumps still require quite a lot of power (~10A) - where
> does it all go? Is it friction in tubes?

There are mainly two types of friction involved. One is skin friction which is the force resisting the motion of a fluid across the surface of a body, in this case the tubes. The other is fluid, or viscous, friction which is the friction between layers of a viscous fluid that are moving relative to each other. For a description of these and other forms of friction, see https://www.google.com/search?q=friction+wikipedia&oq=&aqs=chrome.1.35i39i362l8.1064653256j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

In order to circulate the fluid at a constant rate, the pump must do work to overcome the friction forces that resist the flow.

Hope this helps.